# SAPUI5 Datepicker read only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, sapui5

Does anyone know how to make the SAPUI5 control *sap.m.DatePicker* read only? I would like to be able to show the standard calendar UI to the user if he clicks on the little calendar icon **but** the user shouldn't be allowed to actually change the date.

The only workaround I found so far is to attach a function to the *change* event and reset the value property to the original value. But that's neither good nor pretty.

Here's a little JSBin example with a DatePicker.

```
jQuery(function() {
  var picker = new sap.m.DatePicker();       
  picker.detachEvent("change");

  // is there a better solution than this: `??????
  picker.attachChange(function(oEvent){
    oEvent.getSource().setDateValue(new Date())
  });      

  picker.placeAt('content');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/racoje/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- overriding the .setDateValue() method **for your instance** will disable the date selection.

sap.m.DatePicker source code on [github](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/DatePicker.js) is worth a look.

```
  var picker = new sap.m.DatePicker(); 
  picker.setDateValue = function() {};
```

http://jsbin.com/yirademuwa/1/edit?html,js,output

---

- extending the sap control to overwrite the setDateValue method, final solution by @TimMalich

---

```
$.sap.declare('YOUR.NAMESPACE.DatePicker');
sap.m.DatePicker.extend("YOUR.NAMESPACE.DatePicker", {
    renderer : {},
    init: function() {
        sap.m.DatePicker.prototype.init.apply(this);
    },
    setDateValue : function(){}
});

<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="YOUR.NAMESPACE.controller.VIEW" 
          xmlns:custom="YOUR.NAMESPACE">
    <custom:DatePicker ... />
</mvc>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to bfmags I found a slightly different solution. I need to use this behaviour a couple of times in the UI and I'm using XML views. That's why I extended the sap control to overwrite the setDateValue method as bfmags suggested.

```
$.sap.declare('YOUR.NAMESPACE.DatePicker');
sap.m.DatePicker.extend("YOUR.NAMESPACE.DatePicker", {
    renderer : {},
    init: function() {
        sap.m.DatePicker.prototype.init.apply(this);
    },
    setDateValue : function(){}
});
```

Simple XML View Example:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="YOUR.NAMESPACE.controller.VIEW" xmlns:custom="YOUR.NAMESPACE">
    <custom:DatePicker 
        value="{
            path : 'YourModel>YourDate', 
            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
            formatOptions: {
                pattern: 'dd.MM.yyyy'
            }
        }"
    />
</mvc:View>
```